# understanding C++ header files/libraries and the source code of functions

Tags: c++, header

```
#ifndef CPPREFERENCE_IOSTREAM_H
#define CPPREFERENCE_IOSTREAM_H

#include <ios>
#include <streambuf>
#include <istream>
#include <ostream>
#include <iosfwd>

namespace std {

extern istream cin;
extern ostream cout;
extern ostream cerr;
extern ostream clog;
extern wistream wcin;
extern wostream wcout;
extern wostream wcerr;
extern wostream wclog;

}  // namespace std

#endif // CPPREFERENCE_IOSTREAM_H
```

The code is the iostream header. I am trying to understand how the function cout has been implemented in this header file. Unfortunately though I cannot find it?

Comment: What is your *real* problem? *Why* do you want to know how "cout has been implemented"? Isn't it enough to know that `cout` is a variable of type `ostream` in the `std` namespace?

Comment: In this file `cout` is an extern variable. So to find it, you need to find the `.cpp` file containing the definition. Here, you can only say that `cout` is a `std::ostream` variable

Comment: `I am trying to understand how the function cout has been implemented in this header file` it's not a function and it hasn't been implemented in the header file.

Comment: Usually header files don't contain any implementations. They are just there for the program to know what functions exist elsewhere and how they can be used.

Comment: What is the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You really won't see any implementation here. When you do `#include <iostream>`, all that it does is paste this code to your code. This way compiler will see all the definitions like `extern istream cin` and it knows that there is something like `std::cin`. However that doesn't mean it knows how it is implemented.

The implementation for the C++ Standard Library will come from some `dll` file (on a Windows OS). I think it is `MSVCP*.dll`. This `dll` file will contain compiled machine code specific to that OS.

When you compile your application this `dll` will get linked to it. But you really cannot get the source code for it (people in Microsoft have it). Although you could disassemble that `dll`, to observe the code in it.

Comment: Thanks for this answer, and I appreciate your patience and politeness

Answer (score 0):

Here's how it's implemented in LLVM, if I understand you right, that's what you want?

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/ios.cpp

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/iostream.cpp

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/libcxx/trunk/src/strstream.cpp

Comment: Thank you! I will look that up!